# EXT GWT SimpleComboBox Select not updating

Tags: java, combobox, ejb, gxt

I'm hoping there's a simple resolution for this, but I'm having trouble getting the combobox to display the selected value after updating the selected value.

I'm using SimpleComboValue[BeanModel] as my combobox value.

```
combobox.select(model);
combobox.repaint();
```

This doesn't seem to work for me.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select()` does not cause the select event to fire. Try `setValue()` to display the selected value.

```
combobox.setValue(model);
combobox.repaint();
```